# How to search "hello" but exclude "test" from find grep files

Tags: bash, ubuntu, grep

I want to `search` all files include text "`hello`" but `exclude` the result contains "`test`".

**Here is the example files:**

```
mkdir -p /tmp/test
cd /tmp/test

echo "foo hello" > foo.txt

echo "bar world" > bar.txt
echo "test hello" >> bar.txt
echo "world hello" >> bar.txt
```

**Here is the search for "hello":**

```
# find /tmp/test -type f -name '*' -exec grep -H -i "hello" {} \;
/tmp/test/bar.txt:test hello
/tmp/test/bar.txt:world hello
/tmp/test/foo.txt:foo hello
```

**Now I want to exclude "test" from the above search output:**

```
# find /tmp/test -type f -name '*' -exec grep -H -i "hello" {} \; | grep -v "test"
...Nothing here...
```

**Try other pattern:**

```
# find /tmp/test -type f -name '*' -exec grep -H -i "hello" -v "test" {} \;
grep: test: No such file or directory
/tmp/test/bar.txt:bar world
grep: test: No such file or directory
```

**Here is the expected output:**

```
# find /tmp/test -type f -name '*' -exec grep [commands argumensts here] {} \;
/tmp/test/bar.txt:world hello
/tmp/test/foo.txt:foo hello
```

How to do this `search` and `exclude` for find in files?

Comment: This might help: [Find files that contain a string and do not contain another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/337803/74329) or [How to find files that contain one criterion but exclude a different criterion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/315158/74329)

Comment: I tried the two solutions from that link, both not work as expected: `find /tmp/test -type f -name "*" \( -exec grep -q "hello" {} \; ! -exec grep -q "test" {} \; \) -print` and 
`find /tmp/test -type f -name '*' -exec awk -v RS="\0" '/hello/ && !/test/{print FILENAME}' {} \;`

Comment: You may want to make clear if you are looking for cases where the *file* contains "hello" and does not contain "test", or just looking for lines in the files that contain "hello" and do not contain "test".

Comment: No. The output is wrong. Please see the "`expected output`". Thank you.

Comment: Sorry. I have just changed the title to more suitable. Please check again!

Comment: I mean that your question is unclear since it can be read to mean that you are looking for words anywhere in the file, not line by line in the file. However, I think you mean you want to find all cases of "hello" except where "hello" and "test" are in the same line.  This is a requirement that leads to your sample output. In any event, see this post for more solutions: [grep-for-term-and-exclude-another-term](https://superuser.com/questions/537619/grep-for-term-and-exclude-another-term). So, for a simple solution, you can just grep two times: `grep hello /tmp/test/*.txt | grep -v ":.*test"`

Comment: Note that I added a colon in my second (exclude) search - because unfortunately you are testing by looking for "test" but you also named your file "test.txt" and so "test" shows up in all the results from the first search for hello! Yes - and good point from Kendall, as you now have to beware that colons in your files can mess up this search...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use awk instead of grep:

```
$ find test -type f -exec awk '/hello/&&!/test/{print FILENAME,$0}' {} \;
test/foo.txt foo hello
test/bar.txt world hello
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have `test` in the file path.

You can match for things after the `:` but that will only work if you do not have `:` in the text of the file.

```bash
find /tmp/test -type f -name '*' -exec grep -H -i
```

Example:

```bash
/t/test  ❯❯❯ find /tmp/test -type f -name '*' -exec grep -H -i "hello" {} \; | grep -v -E ".*\:.*test"
/tmp/test/foo.txt:foo hello
/tmp/test/bar.txt:world hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk which can parse file contents very quickly.  The following sample script

```
#!/bin/sh

file1="grepTest1.txt"
echo "dum dum
dum hello dum
crumb test crumb
dum dum" >${file1}

file2="grepTest2.txt"
echo "dum dum
dum hello dum
dum dum" >${file2}

file3="grepTest3.txt"
echo "dum dum
dum test dum
crumb hello crumb
dum dum" >${file3}

file4="grepTest4.txt"
echo "dum dum
crumb jello crumb
crumb bellow crumb
dum test dum
dum dum" >${file4}

for file in grepTest?.txt
do
    awk -v acc="hello" -v rej="test" 'BEGIN{
        good=0 ;
    }
    {
        if( index($0, rej) != 0 ){
            good=2 ;
            exit ;
        }else{
            if( index($0, acc) != 0 ){
                good=1 ;
                line=$0 ;
            } ;
        } ;
    }
    END{
        if( good == 1 ){
            printf("%s: %s\n", FILENAME, line ) ;
        }else{
            if( good == 2 ){
                printf("REJECT: Found %s at line %s in %s.\n", rej, NR, FILENAME ) | "cat >&2" ;
            } ;
        } ;
    }' ${file}
done
```

gives the output

```
REJECT: Found test at line 3 in grepTest1.txt.
grepTest2.txt: dum hello dum
REJECT: Found test at line 2 in grepTest3.txt.
REJECT: Found test at line 4 in grepTest4.txt.
```

BUT ... note that the **3 reject lines go to stderr**.  if you redirect stdout to a file, you will only have the list of good files in that list.

Comment: Note that Kendall's solution will also generate multiple lines per file if there are multiple instances identified in any given file.  *That may or may not be desirable*.  While the above currently does not report multiple instances, that is easily rectified by collecting cases in an array then outputting the array if applicable.